# Правила пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Обязательно ли ставить тире в предложении: "Каждый шестой атом земной коры - это атом кремния"? Или вариант без тире тоже допустим и ошибкой не считается?

Answer (score 2):

Здесь тире обязательно.
(===============)  
§ 166. Тире ставится перед это, это есть, это значит, вот, если сказуемое, выраженное существительным в именительном падеже или неопределенной формой, присоединяется посредством этих слов к подлежащему, например:

Коммунизм – это есть Советская власть плюс электрификация всей страны.
Ленин

Поэзия – это огненный взор юноши, кипящего избытком сил.
Белинский

Романтизм – вот первое слово, огласившее пушкинский период; народность – вот альфа и омега нового периода.
Белинский
(===============)

(Правила-56)

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=tire

Answer (score 1):

Тире ставится обязательно.

Наличие связок ЭТО, ВОТ, ЭТО ЗНАЧИТ между подлежащим  и именной частью сказуемого   является тем единственным случаем, когда авторский выбор не допускается (это особое построение предложения).

В этом случае НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО УТОЧНЯТЬ, какой частью речи выражены главные члены предложения.